# with offline_access migration enabled, trying to extend the access tokens to 60 days seems to fail ~70% of the time. Why would that happen?

Tags: facebook, authentication, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm extending client-side access tokens as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

But I've noticed that very frequently the request returns the short lived access token instead of extending it.  Across all of our users, this appears to be the case ~70% of the time *after* enabling the migration.

Is there something that we can do to fix it? Why might this be failing so frequently?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this happening for only one application?

Comment: Were you using offline_access before? are you sure you're not trying to extend a token which is already long-lived, or infinite?
If not, is this only for old users who've never seen an enhanced auth dialog, or is it also for new users?

Comment: @Guy - this is happening across ~10 applications.

Comment: @Igy - We had previously used offline access for some of those applications, but enabled the migration.  Testing the access tokens with the access token validator shows that they expire in ~2 hours. If that endpoint is called with a long lived access token, the returned access token should still be long according to the docs.  I'm not sure whether or not these users have seen an enhanced auth dialog.  I'll go dig into that. Thanks!

Comment: You know that the actual token string you receive from that endpoint might be the same as the one you pass in? are you sure that they're still short tokens afterwards?

Comment: @Igy, the response has a field containing the number of seconds until it expires.  That's usually around 2 hours worth of seconds.